# Active "Workflows can use app permissions"

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I tried to enable/active the "**Workflows can use app permission**" but I encountered the error below.

[image]

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Have you granted permission to workflow in app permissions page? What kind of task does your workflow do? Are you using app step in your workflow?

Comment: The workflow that I am creating is to set List Item value only. After creating that and tried to add list, workflow is automatically set to cancelled because Workflows can use app permission is disabled. I tried to enable or activate that features buy that's the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows can use app permissions feature is only going to be activated if

1) You have configured your workflow manager properly. Make sure there are not issues with your workflow manager and you can create workflow using SP 2013 Workflow Manager.

2) You have configured apps for SharePoint 2013. Again you will need to make sure that you have hit all the check when configuring SharePoint 2013 apps.

Follow these two articles to make sure that you have configured apps for SharePoint 2013.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Else using correlation ID you can find specific error from ULS log viewer.

Comment: Is it worked for you?...If yes then Please mark and upvote the answer..:)